# how to install dual system in win7?

Tags: windows-7, boot, debian

I have installed win7 in disk c: which the system format is ntfs,now i want to install debian7.5 from my win7.
1)i downloaded  grub4dos ,and unzip it to save all the file under my disk c:
2)edit the boo.ini in disk c:

```
[boot loader]
[operating systems]
c:\grldr.mbr="Grub4dos"
```

3)edit the menu.lst in disk c:

```
title    Install Debian 7.5
kernel    (hd0,0)/vmlinuz 
initrd    (hd0,0)/initrd.gz
boot
```

4)download the two files `initrd.gz`,`vmlinuz` in the disk c: .
5)download the debian7.5.iso in my disk d: which system file format is fat32.

when i reboot my pc ,i can install debian7.5 now ,i install my debian7.5 in the disk e: which the file system is ext4 (it can not be read in win7) ,after my installation ,i install the boot manager in my disk.

when i reboot ,i found that my win7 boot manager is replaced by grub boot manager,so i reinstall my debian and in the last stage, i do not install the boot manager in my pc,when i reboot now ,i can not see my debian boot menu ,only win7 and grub4dos boot menu can be seen,how can i write my debian7.5 boot menu in the boot menu now?
I feel it is complicated  to solve because that in this situation the debian disk partition is in ext4 format and can not be seen in win7 ,i really installed win7 and debian7.5 ,but the debian7.5 can not be booted, how can i fix it ?

Comment: `i reinstall my debian and in the last stage, i do not install the boot manager in my pc`. When you reinstalled your debian the UUID of the partition changed and since you didn't install the bootloader, it's normal that it couldn't find the path to boot. Your best bet is to repeat the process and install the bootloader this time. And you can't use windows bootloader because it won't let you boot to any linux distro. The only way to go is to let GRUB take care of the boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to go to have linux and windows in dualboot is to find a **Live bootable image** or any kind of **bootable** installation media. Once running linux you can edit your partitions and install your OS, I suggest you let the linux distro take care of the boot, Windows is less "friendly" with other OS's.

I don't know if you really need Debian but just in case I suggest you use Fedora, Ubuntu or some distro that is more user-friendly at its installation.